# Different styles of area in same shape layer

Tags: qgis, shapefile, style, area

I'm using QGIS 3.16.

I have the following problems: One of my shape-layer has several areas. Now I want to give every area a different style/colour. I already found the function to give all areas the same style/colour. I had an idea today in the morning that I could multiply or copy the shape-layer and edit in every layer one area and delete the rest. That would make a lot of effort. Does somebody has an other idea to change the areas in the same layer?

In addition, I don't find the function which you can change the graduation of the scale bar. So no 100, 200, 300, 400 steps, instead 50 100 200 400 etc.

Answer (score 3):

In QGIS you can style each area in the symbology options (right-click > Properties). Use "Categorized" and choose the field for the categories. If you really want to style each area differently create an unique identifier using `$id` in the field calculator.

The scale bar you can edit in the Map Canvas. Select your scale bar, select "Item Properties" and go down to "Segments".

Comment: Thank you a lot!

Comment: Welcome! Please mark it as the answer as well for better overview.